# Access denied for user 'user@localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

So I'm stumped with this issue, I'm getting this error code..

```
Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Before you tell me the credentials are incorrect, I'm 100% positive that they are correct. There are three instances in which my script connects to MySQL with these credentials:

1. At the start of the script, to pull user information.
2. Midway through the script, to create a table.
3. A few lines below #2, to insert data into the newly created table.

Now what's confusing me is that these credentials work for #1 and #2, it pulls user information from the database, and creates a table. But when I try to insert data into the table, suddenly the credentials are wrong, and there's no code that's changing the credentials in */inc/database.php*

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I already checked permissions for this users access to the database and all permissions are enabled.

Comment: so show us what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Databases can have distinct permissions for SELECT and INSERT or DELETE queries.

Comment: user permissions is not correct...

Comment: Maybe you're using an escape function that requires db connection passed to it. Impossible to answer at this point, but all guesswork till the cows come home.

Comment: Are you trying to access remote database from other server?

Comment: in your `inc/database.php` can you `var_dump` the variables to see whats being sent?

Comment: Please do `SHOW GRANTS for 'user'@'localhost';`

Answer (score 0):

Ahah! Found the solution for anyone else having this problem. It looks like the MySQL function I was using:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'FILE/PATH/HERE/FILE.csv' INTO TABLE[...]
```

Is disabled, a workaround that usually works is by changing this to:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
```

Newer PHP versions disable the first function for security reasons.

Comment: So, Mario was on the right track. *"Databases can have distinct permissions for SELECT and INSERT or DELETE queries. –  mario"*